# Git completely replaced changes in history. How to restore files?

Tags: eclipse, git, history, restore

I have git repository on bitbucket. I use it from Eclipse for a while, but then copy Eclipse project with local git repository to another place on the filesystem and work locally for 3 weeks. I'm a newbie with git, so I just copy the project as is.

Yesterday I try to push local changes and then switch to the remote branch. Now I see in git-gui only old bitbucket commits and no new files. I search in git-gui everywhere. But the size of the repository tells me that my new files are still there (on bitbucket 16mb, locally >300mb).

`git branch` shows me 2 branches (master and * (no branch)) and both have bitbucket commits. I didn't make any branches, I just first cloned the repo from bitbucket, then made commits, then made some actions trying to push the copied repo and then change branch. Any idea of how can I restore my local files will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really having a hard time understanding what the exact situation is.

However, if you say all the files are still in the local repo, a simple:

```
git reflog
```

is all you need to see recent commits on all branches. Find the right commit you want to go back to, and take it from there.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I will write shorter next time, sorry!